# Yii2 Checkbox list, not checked model values

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Lets talk in code directly.

```
<div class="checkbox-list">
                <?php
                var_dump ($model->categoriesIds); // [1,2] so database has two categries.
                $cats=Category::find()->all(); foreach($cats as $i=>$category){?>
                    <?= $form
                        ->field($model, 'categoriesIds[]')
                        ->checkbox([
                            'label'=>$category->name,
                            'value' => $category->id
                        ])
                        ->label(false)
                    ?>
                <?php } if(count ($cats)==0){ echo '<li>No Categories found.</li>';} ?>
            </div>
```

i've categories's values but it don't check checkboxes based on this array, its saving values as well properly.

Comment: I think this link http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53418-checkboxlist-options/ can help you

Comment: Used chekboxList instance of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkboxlist` to loop your categories

```
 <? 
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    $cats=Category::find()->all();
    $cats=ArrayHelper::map($cats, 'id', 'name');
    echo $form->field($model, 'categoriesIds[]')->checkboxList($cats);
    ?>
```

Comment: its not working, its saving values properly.. but didn't show default checked state for that prevoisly selected checkboxes

Comment: let me know difference between [1,2] (its PHP Array not string) and explode(',','1,2');

Answer (score 0):

all();
    $regs=ArrayHelper::map($reg, 'region_id', 'region_name');

    ?>

```
   <?php echo $form->field($model, 'region_id[]')->checkboxList($regs); ?>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your answer?